# Nest tasks under sections within a list

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-list

I'm using SharePoint 2013 and I am attempting to nest a bunch of tasks within sections for each person (IE: item).

For example: I'd like John Doe to have 3 tasks within HR, 3 tasks within Admin, and 3 tasks within finance. And as he completes those tasks and checks them off there's a record of it occurring. I'd also like to be able to attach a bunch of documents to one person as their "Record".

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint has OOB feature to show current user's task, so you could insert the task view to a page where user will see their own task only(the documents also similar as view, create a user field so you could assign the document to user as their records).

[image]

[image]